# Power BI - Get Slicer to filter Today initially

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible when opening a report, the slicer filters the current day and then if users want to check other dates, they can.

[image]

The "end date" of my slicer captures the current day correctly, but the "start date" always filters by the day that I published my report to the Power BI Service.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a relative date slicer.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have to keep my slicer format as it is in the image